# Magento1 Coupon code Position

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon

I am applying coupon code on Magento ver.1. Its works good but its showing before Shipping & Handling ( I want to moved down after shipping and handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Open **`app/design/frontend/<currentthemepackage>/<currenttheme>/template/checkout/cart.phtml`** file.

**Step 2:** Find and replace the code:

```
<div class="cart-forms">
        <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout_cart_widget') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout.cart.extra') ?>
        <?php if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping'); endif; ?>
    </div>
```

with:

```
<div class="cart-forms">
        <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout_cart_widget') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout.cart.extra') ?>
        <?php if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping'); endif; ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
    </div>
```

**Step 3:** Refresh the cache and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `admin->configuration->sales(left side menu)->Checkout Totals Sort Order` and change order
[image]

**Note : Clear cache**

Comment: how change postion in email

Comment: @sdfas I think if you update here. It will reflect in email in same order.

Comment: not working i tired this but its always show after shipping i want before